# How to pass parameters to flow site page from within community using a navigation menu

Tags: visual-workflow, experience-cloud, parameters, navigation-menu

I have a flow with two input variables. I would like to pass values for these via URL from within community using a navigation menu. The URL field shown in the image doesnt support getting parameters. Is there a specific format to pass these flowArguements? Any help is highly appreciated. [image]