# Reference Dynamic AccountID on Site Page in Experience Cloud (Community)

Tags: experience-cloud

My question is similar to [How to pass parameters to flow site page from within community using a navigation menu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/403381/how-to-pass-parameters-to-flow-site-page-from-within-community-using-a-navigatio) , which did not receive any answers.

I have a Site Page that includes an existing custom component that needs an AccountID as the {!recordId} value to render properly.  (The custom component is used on several other object pages and is dynamic based on the type of record/ID passed in.)

For test purposes I can hard code an AccountID and that works, but I cannot figure out a way to dynamically pass in the actual account id.  This page is referenced from its own Navigation item.

One solution could be to simply use an Account detail object page where recordId would be available, but the Account detail page is already used to display information about the Account.  The Site Page has custom content and needs to be a separate page accessible from the navigation.  I don't seem to be able to create additional account detail object pages, but if that is possible, then that might be a solution and I could switch from a Site Page to an Object page.

Otherwise, is there a way to pass accountid via the Navigation item or through another mechanism.